# Javascript on remove div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();x--;
})
```

Above is my javascript to remove div that was dynamic generated such as

```
<div class="newRow">Some Text &nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>
```

But here the issues that is because I use bootstrap grid column

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="newRow">Some Text</div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="newRow">
                Some Text Part 2&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of remove by 'div' , I would like remove by div class="row"
so it remove the entire row. how do i change my code for it to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.closest()` selector:

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
 e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('.row').remove();x--;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove using `.parent()` like

```js
$(document).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
     $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="newRow">Some Text</div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="newRow">
                Some Text Part 2&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```